# Fail to import into Neo4J with batch-import

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to import a SQLite3 database into Neo4J using [batch-import](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import). Being a Neo4J noob, I followed Max De Marzi's post : [Batch Importer – Part 2](http://maxdemarzi.com/2012/02/28/batch-importer-part-2/).

I get this error:

```
# java -server -Xmx2G -jar /opt/batch-import/target/batch-import-jar-with-dependencies.jar /var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db nodes.csv relations.csv 
Usage: Importer data/dir nodes.csv relationships.csv [node_index node-index-name fulltext|exact nodes_index.csv rel_index rel-index-name fulltext|exact rels_index.csv ....]
Using: Importer /var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db nodes.csv relations.csv

Using Existing Configuration File
..
Importing 271544 Nodes took 2 seconds 

Total import time: 4 seconds 
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: id=271565
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserterImpl.getNodeRecord(BatchInserterImpl.java:917)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserterImpl.createRelationship(BatchInserterImpl.java:471)
    at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.importRelationships(Importer.java:136)
    at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.doImport(Importer.java:214)
    at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.main(Importer.java:78)
```

But the node exists :

```
$ grep ^271565 nodes.csv 
271565  'la Callas' 'n_term'    0.0
```

Has anyone else had this issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show your file headers?

As you can see you only imported `271544` nodes. So there is no way there is a node with the node-id `271565`.

The id in the relationship file refers to the row number in the nodes-file not to what is in your own "id" column (how could it know).

The only thing you can do here is to use `id:id` which is a special type and will force the neo4j-id's to correspond to your provided id's. And in the relationship-file use `start:id`, `end:id`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try an alternate method to import bulk-data into neo4j.

First convert your database into csv files and import it into Gephi - a graph visualization tool. Then by using the Gephi plugin for neo4j database support, you should be able to export your database (from Gephi) into neo4j format.

Finally just copy the exported file into appropriate neo4j directory.

For importing database into Gephi, you will need two csv files - one with all the nodes and other with all the relationships. Follow this tutorial : http://blog.neo4j.org/2013/01/fun-with-beer-and-graphs.html

Get Gephi from here: https://gephi.org/

Get the Plugin from here : https://marketplace.gephi.org/plugin/neo4j-graph-database-support/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Can you supply your input files to test? What branch are you using?

I found a similar error reported here: https://github.com/jexp/batch-import/issues/59

Comment: I am using version 2.0.0. My csv file are too large (9.5Mo, 90Mo) to be posted here. I'll try to create a minimal exemple.